# mergeTo function for linked lists with insert and remove predefined

Tags: java, linked-list

Ok so I'm having a bit of an issue with a mergeTo function that's supposed to merge two linked lists into one (this and that linked lists - merged into this). Here's my code for mergeTo:

```
public void mergeTo(WordLinkedList that){

   Node current = that.firstnode;
   int i = 0;

   while (current != null){ //iterating through all the elements of 'that' list
       this.insert(current.word);//inserting each successive word into 'this'
       that.remove(i); //removing each successive word from 'that'
       current = current.next;//moving the pointer forward
       i++; //moving the counter forward (for the remove function
   }
}
```

My logic with that function is simply to iterate through every element of that linked list - inserting each successive element into 'this' list and then removing it right away (using i as a counter)

Here's my insert function:

```
public void insert(String newword){

  Node newNode = new Node(newword);
  size++;
  Node previous = null;
  Node present = firstnode;

  while ((present != null)&& (newword.compareTo(present.word) > 0)){
      previous = present;
      present = present.next;
  }
  if (present != null && newword.compareTo(present.word)==0){
      size--;
      return;
  }
  if ((previous == null)){
      firstnode = newNode;
  }
  else{
      previous.next = newNode;
  }
  newNode.next = present;
}
```

My insert function is supposed to insert stuff into my linked list whilst keeping alphabetical order. I've tested it and I think it works as expected. I don't believe there's anything wrong with it.

Here's my remove function:

```
public String remove (int i){
   Node present = firstnode;
   Node previous = firstnode;

   if (i > this.size || i < 0)
       throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Hahahahahahaha it's out of bounds!!!!!!!!");

   if (i == 0 && firstnode != null){
       firstnode = firstnode.next;
   }
   else{
   for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
       present = present.next;
   }
   for (int k = 0; k < i-1; k++){
       previous = previous.next;
   }

   previous.next = present.next;
   present.next = null;
   size--;
   }
   return present.word;
}
```

I tested this and for my test cases it works fine, however I think the issue is somewhere in the remove function. If i comment out the remove line from my mergeTo method - the insert works just fine. However if I leave it in there, it does some unexpected behaviour. Here's my testing function:

```
    String[] words6={"eta","gamma", "zeta"};//to test mergeTo
    String[] words7={"alpha","beta","phi"};//to test mergeTo - no common    words with words6
    listObj1=new WordLinkedList(words6);
    listObj2=new WordLinkedList(words7);
    listObj1.mergeTo(listObj2);
    System.out.println("this list: \n"+listObj1.toString());
    System.out.println("size of this list = " + listObj1.getSize());
    System.out.println("that list: \n"+listObj2.toString());
    System.out.println("size of that list = " + listObj2.getSize());
```

And my supposed output:
Test 17 - mergeTo
this list: 
alpha
beta
eta
gamma
phi
zeta
size of this list = 6
that list: 
The list is empty
size of that list = 0

And my actual output:
this list: 
alpha
beta
eta
gamma
zeta
size of this list = 5
that list: 
beta
size of that list = 2

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured out how to fix the issue :). In the mergeTo method,  that.remove(i) should be changed to that.remove(0) - the remove method removes the first index every time.